# How often do Market app statistics update?

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded my app to the market last night, and after an hour or so it showed 107 installs, 88 active, 2 comments. It still says that (12+ hours later), even though when I click comments there are 10+. How often do the statistics update? Is there any way to update them manually?

Comment: I think it's every 24 hours.  If it's a paid app you can get more recent information from the orders inbox on Google Checkout.

Comment: I'll monitor the situation and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would guess for once in 24 hours. It may once in 12 hours but I'm not sure and I don't now if there are better informations on this.

Comment: I guess the same. The comments/rating updates more often, but thats just a feeling. The statistic update itself is not at the same time, again just a feeling.

Comment: From personal experience, I would say its ever 24 hours, I wish it was atleast every 12 or 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

By now it takes about **3 days** for me to update data.

This is an example from my app:
[image: Example: Finger Wars app statistics]